# Django admin query to list specific records

Tags: django, django-admin

Say I have a model named `Foobar` in the `foobar` app, to list the record #1 in the back office, the url will be :

http://djangosite.com/admin/foobar/foobar/?q=1

Is it possible to have a valid url to list multiple records, for example records #1 AND #6 AND #42 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `http://djangosite.com/admin/foobar/foobar/?q=1&q=2&q=3`. In Django view you can use [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to get all q values:

```
request.GET.getlist('q')
```